# Buy X Get Y Free Coupon in Magento

Tags: magento

I am using Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.0. I want to make a shopping cart rule where customer buys 1 product from some category and he gets 1 free product from any other category for free. Free product will be a preselected one at the time of rule creation.

Is this possible without using any extension or is there a free extension for this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes here is good extension and it is free

i am using it in one of my magento. working good for me

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gift-for-product-bought-3301.html

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

there is one more extension for this functionality which work using coupon code.
only one draw back there, it is not compatible with one step checkout

http://blog.gaiterjones.com/free-magento-extension-buy-one-get-one-free-discounted/